# How to set Initial Route from native iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

**I'm integrate Flutter module to ios Native project, I want to set Initial Route from ios native, but it not work, it use default route.**

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "test")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        flutterEngine.navigationChannel.invokeMethod("setInitialRoute", arguments:"/home")
        flutterEngine.run();

    }

    @IBAction func handleClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        flutterViewController.setInitialRoute("/home")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(flutterViewController, animated: true)
    }

}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _route = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/login": (context) => Login(),
    "/home": (context) => Home()
  };

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: _route,
      title: "App", // Title ของหน้า
      home: Scaffold(
        // หน้าจอหลัก
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("App Navi"),
        ),
        body: Login(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Login, Home file please see in image, beacause stackoverflow can't to post text "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Add code as text instead of Screenshots

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha I'm sorry, I've edit post it.

Comment: Hi if my answer is working for you , you can mark it as accepted .

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now fixed and as of **Flutter 1.22** it can be done using:

While initializing flutter engine:

```
let flutterEngine = FlutterEngine()
// FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint is the same as nil, which will run main().
engine.run(
  withEntrypoint: FlutterDefaultDartEntrypoint, initialRoute: "/onboarding")
```

and, Directly while creating the `FlutterViewController`,

```
 let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(
    project: nil,
    initialRoute: "/onboarding",
    nibName: nil,
    bundle: nil)
```